# Definition of MDS Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have two definitions for MDS (Maximum Distance Separable) Matrix:

**First definition:** A matrix $M$ of order $n$ is an MDS matrix if and only if every sub-matrix of $M$ is non-singular.

**Second definition:** A matrix $M_{n\times n}$ is MDS if and only if

$$
Y_{n\times 1}=M_{n \times n}\, X_{n \times 1} \Longrightarrow \mathop{\rm min}_{X\neq 0}(W(Y)+W(X))=n+1
$$

where $X={[x_0,x_1,\cdots , x_{n-1}]}^T$ and $Y={[y_0,y_1,\cdots , y_{n-1}]}^T$ are vectors  in an arbitrary 
 field and $W(X)$ is the number of non-zero elements of $X$.

I have two questions:

> Is it possible to make an example a matrix of order at least $3$ and by second definition proof 
>    that is an MDS matrix and my next question is that Is there a suitable book or article about MDS matrix.

In fact, I am researching about new simple definition or conditions such that a matrix be MDS.

I would be appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: There seem to be two distinct questions here: 1) How to construct a 3-by-3 MDS matrix and verify using the 2nd definition, 2) Review articles / books on MDS matrices. I can say nothing to the former, but Wikipedia's page on [MDS matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix) includes some references which may(?) be useful.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for comment and edition. I saw wiki page but It was not useful for me. In fact, they construct MDS matrix by Cauchy matrix and Vandermonde matrix. I mean, they do not test a arbitrary matrix by definition. just because of this fact, I asked this question.

Comment: @Semiclassical Is it right to say that the number of square sub-matrix of a square matrix of order $n$ is 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\,{ n \choose i}^2
$$
Is there any sequence numbers in [Oeis](http://oeis.org/) for the number of these sub-matrices. Excuse me because I asked too questions.

Comment: @xxx--- Maybe you find [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47155/prove-the-branch-of-number-of-advanced-encryption-standard/47161#47161) useful.